# how to use codepen code into my own website

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, loading, codepen

I am building my own portfolio site and I want to use a loading animation on my homepage. I am just starting to code like moving from Adobe Muse to coding part but I found this codepen post for loading animation. But the problem is I couldn't find to use on my website.

Comment: Codepen Link : https://codepen.io/v_trefil/pen/oxmdqw

Comment: You should go back to square 1 and research a bit more on the topic of adding CSS and JavaScript to your pages. Also, I recommend trying to fully understand what the code in the pen does before pasting it into your site.

Comment: Thank you. But I am beginner now. I am learning but sometime it is hard to find some exact solutions. Any suggestions on that ? Really thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, adding CSS and JavaScript to pages *is* beginner level stuff. It's one of the first things you need to learn if you want to do web development.

Answer (score 0):

You can you try exporting your pen and then use it locally or even use it in your website.

There are two ways to export your Pens from CodePen. You can download a .zip archive of the Pen, or export it to GitHub as a Gist. You'll find both of these options in the "Export" menu at the bottom of the editor.

[image]

Here is a step by step tutorial to acheive it.

https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/exporting-pens/

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @hayavuk Sorry, I didn't read the post correctly initially, Edited it anyways.. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I tried those export to local but still confused or not able to find the solution in the which I want to work on the website.